# Child theme in Wordpress not loading using functions.php instead of @import

Tags: php, css, wordpress, child-theming

I've searched through several questions and still having trouble. I'd really appreciate some expertise from y'all. =)

The child theme created and activated on my WordPress site seems to be enacting no changes.

I know essentially zero PHP but trying to use the functions.php instead of @import since it's supposed to be a better load time.

Here's what I have in my child theme's directory style.css (first) and functions.php (second)

```
/*
Theme Name: Quest-Child
Description: No Coward's Quest Child Theme
Author: Jason from No Coward
Author URI: http://www.nocoward.com
Template: quest 
Version: 1.0
*/

/* add padding to site description */
.site-description {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.body {
    background: red;
}

/* can be found on "Services" page. Is the first ID within the <p> element */
#cc-m-12571703896 {
    background: blue;
}
```

---

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'quest-all-css'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

WordPress recognizes the child theme and has allowed me to activate it successfully.

The stuff in CSS is what I've tried to use for testing my child-theme laying down my changes. Nothing is appearing.

Again, I have zero PHP knowledge. Based on [the official WordPress "How to create a child theme"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), I copied and pasted the code above and tried to fill in the "parent-style" value based on their instructions.

Here's what I saw on my parent theme I could possibly be using for the functions.php "parent-style"...

```
// Enqueue required styles
            wp_enqueue_style( 'quest-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'smartmenus', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/smartmenus/addons/bootstrap/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/animate/animate.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'slit-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/FullscreenSlitSlider/css/style.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'colorbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/colorbox/colorbox.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'Quest-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(
                'quest-bootstrap',
                'smartmenus',
                'font-awesome',
                'animate-css',
                'slit-slider',
                'colorbox'
            ) );

...

// Enqueue required styles
            wp_enqueue_style( 'quest-all-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/plugins-all.min.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'Quest-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'quest-all-css' ) );

            // Enqueue required scripts
            wp_enqueue_script( 'quest-all-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/quest-and-plugins.js', array(
                'jquery',
                'masonry'
            ) );
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!
-Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this. Here's the PHP code I found on the help forum. I think the "Portfolio" bit may be extraneous, but it's working so I'm leaving it there just in case.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'quest_child_enqueue_styles' );
function quest_child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_filter( 'quest_plus_template_content-portfolio', 'quest_child_template_portfolio' );

function quest_child_template_portfolio(){
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/content-portfolio.php';
}
```

Caveat to this solution: There is a weird thing happening. I put in some styling to make something "Background: red" so I could test if the child theme was working, and despite deleting that bit of code, it is still appearing.

For now I'm chalking it up to slow hosting but be aware that's happening if you follow this solution.

Hope this helps someone else! =)

Jason